# Cannot split a seemingly encoded string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, latin1

While parsing data from a web request, I came across the following string -

```
dateRange = 'September\xa04,\xa01978 – September 1980'
```

The encoding of the extracted string seems to be Latin-1 (based on `\xa0`). I got rid of that by replacing the codes with spaces.

```
dateRange = dateRange.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
```

Keeping that aside, I can't split the string on the hyphen(-).

When I call split() as follows:

```
print(dateRange.split('-'))
```

The output is as follows:

```
['September\xa04,\xa01978 – September 1980']
```

It is as if there was no hyphen in the string.
I sense that it has something to do with the encoding, but I can't seem to comprehend the issue exactly.

So, how to work around this issue?

EDIT:

I have already tried the following to no avail:

```
dateRange.split('\-')
```

Comment: – (the character in your dateRange) and - the character you are splitting on do not appear to be the same thing.  Assuming you've accurately pasted them you've got different characters: –-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an [hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm). That's an [U+2013 ᴇɴ ᴅᴀsʜ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

Just copy & paste it into your split call:

```
dateRange.split('–')
```

Alternatively, you can replace it with an actual hyphen. Make sure to copy & paste the en dash into the replace call :)

Comment: And if you are going to put literal Unicode in your source, remember to declare the source file `coding=`; see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: I used the unicode literal like this - `dateRange.split(u'\u2013')`. It did the trick.

Comment: @msw - Thanks for the pointer. I have incorporated your advise as well.